# Landing big jumps in Skate 2

Tags: skate-2

There's a Skate Magazine challenge in Skate 2 called "Who Lives Here?" where you basically have to jump an enormous gap. I have no idea how to do it. I can make the gap easy, but whenever I land I bail. Are there any tips on how to land big jumps?

Comment: (I found a ramp that I put at the bottom that allowed me to land the jump I was stuck on, but the main question still stands: how _do_ you land big jumps in general?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, leaning forward (slightly up on the right stick) should allow you to land a bigger jump/air. It won't allow you to jump off buildings and stick landings, but it will improve the chance of landing without bailing.

Also, of course, make sure to land straight and clean to further improve the odds of success, assuming a flat surface.

Answer (score 0):

When I played I noticed that whenever you jump from a certain height and land on a flat surface you fall, so my advice is to try to land into ramps or into half pipe ramps. I think there was no penalty height for the latter.

Answer (score -1):

when you land grab both trigger as your hitting flat and keep straight

Answer (score -1):

Land in a slope, and you will do fine.